# how can i view Sunday birthday of employee in Saturday web page only using php and mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql

i need some code to view birthday of employee of Sunday in Saturday sheet only using php and mysql

```
$sql = "
select Name
     , Designation
     , Department 
  FROM employeebirth 
 where MONTH( Date_of_birth ) = MONTH( CURDATE( ) ) 
   AND DAYOFMONTH( Date_of_birth ) = DAYOFMONTH( CURDATE( ) ) ";
```

how can i continue with the same query further i need some help....

Comment: What's a Sunday birthday? What's a Saturday webpage? Why are these different from any other day of the week?

Comment: do you want to show birthday list one day before ? 
i think it'll help [link](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/MySQL/0280__Date-Time-Functions/DATEADDcurdateINTERVAL1DAY.htm)

Answer (score 0):

If what you mean by Sunday is the next day after today (assuming today is Saturday), then you just need to add 1 day to it :

```php
$sql = "
select Name
     , Designation
     , Department 
  FROM employeebirth 
 where MONTH( Date_of_birth ) = MONTH( CURDATE( ) ) 
   AND DAYOFMONTH( Date_of_birth ) = DATEADD(day, 1, DAYOFMONTH( CURDATE() )) ";
```

Comment: I suppose one might vaguely hope that if this is what the OP wanted, then they would have said so - but we shall see.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by PHP as below:

```
$sql = "select Name, Designation, DepartmentFROM employeebirth 
 where MONTH( Date_of_birth ) = MONTH( CURDATE( ) ) AND ";

$currentWeekDay = date("w"); 
if ($currentWeekDay == 6) { //Checking if today is saturday
    $sql .= " DAYOFMONTH( Date_of_birth ) IN (DAYOFMONTH( CURDATE( ) ), DATEADD(day, 1, DAYOFMONTH( CURDATE() )) ) ";
} else {
    $sql .= " DAYOFMONTH( Date_of_birth ) = DAYOFMONTH( CURDATE( ) ) ";
}
```

You need to check if the day is **Saturday** and then need to make a `where in` query for checking current and next day date. Hope it helps you!!

Comment: i tried ur query but i am getting an error like this:Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in D:\wamp64\www\emp_new\index.php on line 31
Call Stack...